# What's the difference between cmake vs cmake3?

Tags: cmake, clion

I'm been working with CLion when I would update his cmake version to use my default cmake binary, so : "**/usr/bin/cmake**".

When I entered cmake's path, there is two binaries matching the expression : "**/usr/bin/cmake**" and "**/usr/bin/cmake3**". It puzzled me with some questions.

What's the difference between that two and which one to use ?

Comment: Try this: `/usr/bin/cmake --version` and `/usr/bin/cmake3 --version` and see whether the result yields any insights.

Comment: You can try `ls -la /usr/bin/cmake*`. In my case I can see `/usr/bin/cmake -> /usr/bin/cmake3`. That means that cmake is a symbolic link to cmake3. Both are same.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasSablik, I didn' think to try using `ls`, thank you for this quick response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Thomas Sablik mentioned, `/usr/bin/cmake` is simply a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/cmake3`. This is the practice of *many* binaries in Linux - having a symbolic link to a specific version of a binary. In many cases, multiple binaries are installed simultaneously. When/If CMake 4 is released, presumably it will be placed in `/usr/bin/cmake4`, and the symbolic link updated by the installation.

However, `cmake` actually goes a step further in its versioning, because in your CMakeLists.txt, you must use the [`cmake_minimum_required`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/cmake_minimum_required.html) statements, ensuring that your script will not run, unless it is run with a compatible version.

Comment: cmake is not necessarily a symbolic link. For example on Centos 6 and 7 cmake and cmake3 are different binaries.